# Crash in WaitForSingleObject with boost::thread::native_handle()

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, boost

I am seeing a crash in following piece of code. This method is waiting for a thread to complete which was created using boost::thread() api .  As per boost [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread.attributes.nativehandle) below code seems correct but I observe the following behavior consistently

If the thread T1 has already completed by the time call reach to WaitforSingleObject, means a stale handle is passed in waitforSingleObject then nothing happens and it returns 0.
But if Thread T1 is still in to  existence and control reaches to waitforSingleObject(), means a valid handle is passed to waitforSingleObject but it immediately crash.

Problematic code-

```
void waitForJoin( volatile int &exit_now, boost::thread &T1  )  {

.........
.........
WaitForSingleObject( T1.native_handle(), INFINITE );  // Crashes here. 
........
........

}
```

When I replaced the WaitForSingleObject() with join() method then things work fine.

```
void waitForJoin( volatile int &exit_now, boost::thread &T1  )  {

.........
.........
T1.join() // Works.
........
........

}
```

My questions are -

1. Is there something wrong in the first piece of code. As per the boost documentation it seems fine.
2. Even if there is problem that should be other way around i.e. WaitForSinfleObject() should crash if stale handle passed to it not when a valid handle passed to it. Any thoughts ?
3. Is my approach to fix the bug correct ?

Note - I couldn't debug this problem  because in debugger by the time control reaches to WaitForSingleObject in debugger, T1 already completes it's execution so I don't observe any crash.

Comment: just edit T1's code and put something like 5 min sleep there, then debug waitForJoin. What kind of crash do you have?

Comment: @Peter  If I try to debug OR turn on all debug traces then problem doesn't happen. What are we trying to achieve with 5 min sleep in T1 ?  It's application crash.

Comment: With no Join() call, T1 ceases to exist and calling native_handle() blows up?  Separate the calls - load the result from native_handle() into a temp handle and see if it's the NH or WFSO that fails..

Comment: from the documentation of `WaitForSingleObject()` : If this handle is closed while the wait is still pending, the function's behavior is undefined. perhaps this is the case?

Comment: @RonenKr I thought so but if you read the problem again. if handle is closed then I don't see problem. Problem happens when boost thread is still running.

Comment: @MartinJames I added a trace just before WFSO call and I see a valid native_handle which is passed to it.

Comment: can you add the the exact exception text please?

Comment: While you keep repeating that your application crashes you have not described what you mean by that. There are lots of scenarios that people would call a "crash", including deterministic process shutdown due to an unhandled exception. Also, have you tried running a *Release* build under a debugger and enable breaking into the debugger when an SEH (Win32) exception is thrown? If not you should.

Comment: @IInspectable, well I am using release build. SEH is not used in this piece of code may be I should check with SEH if any exception is thrown. I didn't answer to my questions though.

Comment: SEH is **always** used when calling into the Windows API. SEH is the standard exception handling and reporting facility built into Windows. There is no way to not use it.

Comment: What do you mean by "it immediately crash"

Comment: @DavidHeffernan , Application crashes in WFSO api.

Comment: You've got to do better than "crashes". Diagnostics and error messages please.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Actually I am stuck as I mentioned if I try to debug everything works fine. I posted what doesn't and what I think is a solution. Still Let me try to collect more information and come back.  I am no boost expert so trying to find out possible errors in code posted.